# How to recognize single digit in string to insert leading zero?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split, leading-zero

In Python, I have a string with either two digits or one digit:

`8 5E 9C 52 30 0`

In every one digit in the string, I would like to add a leading zero to it (e.g. convert `5` to `05`) and make it two digits.

Thought of splitting, `.split(‘ ‘)`, and checking each one by one and converting each one digit to two digits with: `.zfill(2)`.

So my question is, is there a way to recognize all single digit in a string, and convert all of them to two digits by inserting a leading zero?

Comment: Are you saying you've tried other methods and want to know if there's a faster way? The way you described is the way I would do it.

Comment: `split()` should do the work did you try or you need other methods

Comment: `prefilled = " ".join([x.zfill(2) for x in my_string.split()])`

Comment: wait, do you want 9C to become 09C or remain untouched?

Comment: @JacobIRR all 2 digits should be untouched

Answer (score 7):

Well the nice thing about `zfill(..)` is that if the content contains two characters, that string remains untouched. So you can simply use a generator (or list comprehension) and `' '.join(..)` the result back together:

```
result = ' '.join(x.zfill(2) for x in data.split())
```

Which generates:

```
>>> data = '8 5E 9C 52 30 0'
>>> ' '.join(x.zfill(2) for x in data.split())
'08 5E 9C 52 30 00'
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution with a list comprehension.

**Code:**

```
def pad_hex_str(hex):
    return ' '.join(['0' + h if len(h) == 1 else h for h in hex.split()])
```

**Test Code:**

```
hex_str = '8 5E 9C 52 30 0'
print(pad_hex_str(hex_str))
```

**Results:**

```
08 5E 9C 52 30 00
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` and use `zfill` will work fine.

```
st = "8 5E 9C 52 30 0"
res = ""
for i in st.split():
        res += " " + i.zfill(2)  
print res

#output
08 5E 9C 52 30 00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\b\d\b)', r'0\1', string)
>>> '08 5E 9C 52 30 00'
```

Don't forget to import re of course

Comment: Sorry but do you mind explaining what it's doing for learning purposes? And what `re` I need to import?

Comment: Jo, re is the library for regular expression. I mean "import re". re.sub matches a substring in the first regular expression, and replaces is with second. For matching single digit, it is '\b\d\b', "\d" is for the digit and "\b" for spaces. the brackets outside is to group it. In the second string, \1 is for the group (for which I used brackets before), and 0 is preceding the group. I hope i made it clear. Please consider upvoting. Thanks!

Comment: sorry but still don't understand `r'0\1'`. What do you mean by group and preceding the group?

Comment: A point of clarification: `\b` is **not** *spaces*. `\b` is an anchor for a [word boundary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: @JoKo Please see the example on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6RyBu7/1). It does a good job of showing you how the regex works, as well as providing an explanation.

Comment: Jo, when you added brackets outside, I mean if we write r'(\b\d\b)' instead of r'\b\d\b', we can refer to it as a group. For example (?<!\S)\d(?![^\s.,?!]) this has two groups and we can alias (?<!\S) as '\1' and (?![^\s.,?!]) as '\2'. That is the way to append and substitute in re

Comment: @JoKo regex can be hard to understand and is a language all in it's own. The example above is using "regex" to match the string. I think the other examples might be better with what you are wanting.

Comment: @AbhishekMenon You may wish to review [StackOverflow's markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). The backtick ` (on most keyboards above tab) is used to format code, which makes it easier to read.

Comment: @TemporalWolf. Thanks for the tip. I am just beginning my life in stack overflow. Thanks for being helpful. It is hard to find good people the days. Cheers ;)